# How can I change the language of Windows Live Mail?

Tags: language, windows-live-mail

My mother-in-law (84) finally accepted replacing her old Windows 7 PC by a Win 10 machine. She has a Dutch version of Windows and uses Windows Live Mail (I know: discontinued eons ago), but at her age I'd like her to keep using the software she knows.

I managed to install Live Mail (had to disconnect from internet), but changing the user language from English to Dutch doesn't work. I ran `Langselector` which in turn runs Windows Essentials 2012 Setup again, but disabling Internet doesn't work here; it looks like Setup really needs to download the language resource files. Those are no longer available for download, so it ends with an error message.

Is there a way to change the language of Live Mail under Windows 10, or a download with Dutch as default language? I'm trying to secure our inheritance here (JK!).

Comment: If you've upgraded her to Windows 10 for the security aspect of it, using WLM is probably a bigger risk than Windows 7.

Comment: @towe — Actually, we replaced her 10 years old PC, and a new PC comes with the latest version of Windows, i.e. Win 10. (And I also don't believe that Win 10 wouldn't have any security issues.)

Answer (score 1):

If you still have the old PC laying around, you could (maybe) see if you can find the langpack on it and transfer it to the new PC through a USB? Sorry, but I don't have enough points to leave it as a comment to the original post.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. The old PC is still there, so I can try it. (Later this week, I'm not near the PC at the moment). Alternatively I could copy the whole installation folder to the new PC, and hope that it won't give conflicts with registry entries. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm curious: did it work?